# Dependency injection: Is there a better way than new A(new B(new C ()))?

Tags: design-patterns, dependency-injection

I'm just learning about dependency injection. Unfortunately, I don't have the luxury and time to learn a DI framework right now so I am attempting to do DI through some simple means.

Say I have an object A, that requires a class B, and class B requires class C. When I go to create Object A, is it best practice to create the object like

```
A instanceOfA = new A(new B(new C ()))
```

My question is *Is there a better way to do this*?

Comment: End result will be same, just do this in more readable and comprehensible manner for yourself and teammates.

Comment: What does "better" mean for you in this specific case?

Comment: The better way *is* a DI framework.

Comment: @Omegastick DI frameworks are in no way better than pure DI. They just make developments more productive and some make the code cleaner at expenses of comprehension (it's not obvious how and when the dependency graph is solved). Moreover, some DI frameworks are not declarative, what basically force the developer to solve the dependency graph by instantiating and invoking the framework's API, what doesn't make the solution better than pure DI in any way,

Comment: @Omegastick, from my experience, until someone understands why DI frameworks are *not* better than pure DI, they should only use pure DI. Once they have a good grasp of pure DI, they are then in a position to weigh up the pros and cons that Laiv mentions and decide whether to switch to a framework. I personally prefer comprehension over simplicity and so generally still with pure DI, but others reach the alternative, equally valid conclusion and adopt a framework.

Comment: Hey Laiv, when I mean better approach, I just mean I don't want to have a lot of nested "newing" of objects to create 1 object. For instance if I have some complex class and it may need many dependencies I have to do what I just showed above. It seems though that what I just mentioned may also just be a design problem but I haven't seen this out in the wild. I know I could create a factory so I don't have to do it every time but I'm just wondering if this is even a commonly followed pattern or if I'm shooting myself in the foot

Comment: This _is_ a common problem, and is most commonly solved by using a DI framework. This "nested newing of objects" is exactly the pain that DI frameworks are designed to relieve.

Comment: "better" is subjective and highly depends on your usecase. If A, B, C are services that work together then DI frameworks can help you to whire this up. If type "A" is a Car-Configuration for a Car-buying-system where you need many different objects of (one customer wants the car in blue color the other wants it installed with special radio) then the answer of "better" would be using a [Builder_pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern). If you have a more specific usecase example and a defintion what you mean by "better" you probably get an answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The better pattern is to remember that C also needs to be followed by a pair of parenthesis.

But seriously, yes this is called pure DI. You don't need a framework. It's just good old fashioned reference passing.

My basic pattern is to get inside a method that is called once (usually main), build an object graph, hold on to one object in the graph, and call it's start method to start the whole thing running.

In your case that would look like `instanceOfA.start();`. That gets you out of the static main and into some actual OOP code. Keep construction code and behavior code as separate as you can.

You can do it all again for more transitory objects like timestamps and such that need constructing later but this first bit should get your long lived objects up and going.

Comment: Cool thanks. What do you mean though to say "hold one to one object in the graph and call it's start method?"

Comment: In your case that would look like `instanceOfA.start();`. That gets you out of the static main and into some actual OOP code.  Keep construction code and behavior code as separate as you can.